# Yield keyword giving unexpected values for IEnumerable

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield

This is my code (extension method)

```
public static IEnumerable<uint> GetFieldVals(this DataSource rs, IEnumerable<string> columnNames, Predicate<uint> shouldRun)
        {
            var rList = new List<uint>();
            if (columnNames.Any())

                foreach (var name in columnNames)
                {
                    rs.GetFieldVal(name, out uint temp);
                    if (shouldRun(temp))
                    {
                        rList.Add(temp);
                    }

                }
            return rList;
        }
```

This works. However, if I change it to this, the results are all the final item in the generated collection (although the Count is correct value).

```
public static IEnumerable<uint> GetFieldVals(this DataSource rs, IEnumerable<string> columnNames, Predicate<uint> shouldRun)
{

    if (!columnNames.Any()) yield break;

    foreach (var name in columnNames)
    {
        rs.GetFieldVal(name, out uint temp);
        if (shouldRun(temp))
        {
            yield return temp;
        }

    }
}
```

What gives?

**EDIT**
Thank you everyone for your comments. I had written this in a bit of a hurry and then had a busy weekend, so I was unable to properly address this. I will do so now. You're all 100% correct that I left out too much.

I am attempting to take a clunky DataSource api and create an IEnumerable of valueobject items with it (which is easier and more flexible to work with). I am implementing this using a factory to keep it portable; my factory method implementation calls the code I wrote in my original post. This is a sample of what my valueobject looks like:

```
public class MyTableDataObject : IDataObject<uint>
{
    public uint ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //MOAR properties

    public IEnumerable<uint> SomeCollection { get; set; }

    //MOAR properties

}
```

The issue I spoke about occurs when I have a collection of some type as a property in my valueobject (ie "SomeCollection" in the snippet above)

FWIW, here's my code for the collection of columnnames That I pass to the extension method from my original post.

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> ColumnNames
    {
        get
        {

            yield return "COLUMNNAME00";
            yield return "COLUMNNAME01";
            yield return "COLUMNNAME02";
            yield return "COLUMNNAME03";
            yield return "COLUMNNAME04";
            yield return "COLUMNNAME05";
            yield return "COLUMNNAME06";
            yield return "COLUMNNAME07";
            yield return "COLUMNNAME08";
            yield return "COLUMNNAME09";
            yield return "COLUMNNAME10";
            yield return "COLUMNNAME11";
            yield return "COLUMNNAME12";
            yield return "COLUMNNAME13";
            yield return "COLUMNNAME14";
            yield return "COLUMNNAME15";
        }
    }
```

Here is the calling code.

```
var rs = new DataSource();
rs.Open("Select * From MyTable");

//The Generic type on the enumerable indicates the type of the identifier of the items, not that the Enumerable is itself a list of uints. Do not get confused by this!
var dse = new DataSourceEnumerable<uint>(rs, new MyTableDataObjectFactory());

using (var writer = new MyWriterFacade("MyOutput.json"))
{
    var json = new JsonSerializer(); //Newtonsoft.Json lib
    var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dse, Formatting.Indented);
    writer.Write(str);   

}
```

While the output json file's values are mostly correct, each "SomeCollection" has the same items in it (I believe it's the last item's SomeCollection values) when I use the yield keyword. When I don't use yield and use more traditional code, though, the json output illustrates the correct values for each SomeCollection in the file.

This is the code in the actual Enumerable:

```
public DataSourceEnumerable(DataSource ds, DataObjectFactory<T, DataSource> factory)
{
    ds.MoveFirst();
    innerList = new List<IDataObject<T>>();

    _enumerator = Create(ds, factory, innerList);
}

public static IEnumerator<IDataObject<T>> Create(DataSource ds, DataObjectFactory<T, DataSource> factory,
    IList<IDataObject<T>> innerList)
{   
    while (!ds.Eof)
    {
        innerList.Add(factory.InitializeDataObject<object, object>(ds));
        ds.MoveNext();
    }
    return new DataSourceEnumerator(innerList);
}
```

I hope that sheds some light on it, if anyone can break that down for me a bit better. Appreciate it!

Comment: Please show the code you are using to call this method, I want to see what iteration mechanism you are using

Comment: This code looks ok - it seems that it's probably something to do with the way in which you're calling it. Can you include the calling code too?

Comment: How do you iterate the `IEnumerable<uint>` result? It looks, that you've captured the variable somewhere in a loop in a `linq` method

Comment: Please make a small **complete, indepdently runnable** program that reproduces the error and post it. By doing so, either you will find the defect yourself, or you will present code in a way that lets someone actually run it and understand it.  The code that you've pasted here is fine, so it will be hard to understand what the problem is.

Comment: Can you say a little about why you are calling `Any` before a `foreach` loop?  The `foreach` will skip the body if the collection is empty, so this appears to be useless code.

Comment: Added calling code. @EricLippert You're correct about the Any part. I messed up one small part of it, edited that code to reflect what I actually did

Answer (score 4):

The only real difference in the code as shown relates to *timing*. With the list version, the operations are performed when the method is called. With the yield version, it is called later, when the *result* of the method is actually *iterated*.

Now: things can sometimes.change between calling a method that returns a sequence, and iterating that sequence. For example, the content of the data source or field sequence parameters could change. Or the logic of the predicate could change, usually due to "captured variables". So: the difference is in the code that *calls this*, which we can't see. But: look for *timing* between calling the method, and actually iterating over it (`foreach` etc).